# How do I add tooltips?

Tags: jquery

I would like to display tooltips that contain other HTML content when users hover over certain elements. How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: Take a look http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style or http://qtip2.com/demos

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ show: { duration: 800 } });
```

Here is [JSFiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Handyman/fNjFF/11/)